# Refreshed access token with refresh token, but gateway rejects it as invalid access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 as API gateway for my application. Authentication and Authorization are working as expected.

But I've encountered an issue where I've successfully refreshed an access token using a refresh token, but the gateway still treats the access token as invalid. Can anyone provide insights or solutions to resolve this problem?

My scenario can be reproduced by doing these steps

1. Login with service provider
2. Access token and refresh token granted
3. Make some change in service provider
4. Access token is invalid for the ne request. But token exchange is happening and it's generating new access and refresh token
5. Newly generated access token is invalid according to gateway/apim

I have tried setting pool_size to 0 as I assume the problem is with persistence. but the issue is still there

[Token persistence](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/token-api/#token-persistence)